# trouble dealing with a syntax error in python codes

Tags: python, sql

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle TEXT);")

with open('/Users/hyunjincho/Desktop/twitter_handle.csv','r') as fin:
     reader = csv.reader(fin)
     dicts = ({'twitter_handle': line[0]} for line in reader)
     to_db = ((i['twitter_handle']) for i in dicts)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle)', to_db)
con.commit()
```

python is throwing error at the line

```
  cur.execute('INSERT INTO TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle)', to_db)
```

the error message is

```
   near ")": syntax error
```

I do not know why python is throwing this error as I don't see any error in my code. 
But since I am new to python, there may well be an error that I cannot spot.

EDIT:
 following is the full-traceback of the error

```
        OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-15-9039bb2204be> in <module>()
        46     to_db = ((i['twitter_handle']) for i in dicts)
        47 
   ---> 48 cur.execute('INSERT INTO TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle)', to_db)
        49 con.commit()
        50 

   OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

Comment: What lines are within the `with open` block? You didn't indent it properly in the question.

Comment: This isn't a Python syntax error, it's a SQL syntax error. Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: I thought it was a python error..like I said, I am new to this python and sql thing. should I delete the question and ask this with sql tag?

Comment: No, that's not necessary since you can edit it, and because the problem is specific to how you constructed the command in Python.

Comment: I think you are missing a `;` at the end of the sql statement

Comment: I added ";" at the end and its still throwing an error:

Comment: OperationalError: near ";": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax should be:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle) VALUES(?)', to_db)
```

Where the `?` refers to the parameter `to_db`

Comment: I tried `cur.execute('INSERT INTO TWITTER_HANDLE (twitter_handle) VALUES(to_db)')` but it is still throwing me an error - this time it says `invalid parameter`

Comment: No I meant the `?` symbol is like a placeholder of the actual parameter. Just replace your line with the one I provided in this answer. 
Check out the [sqlite3 module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for more information and to see examples of what I mean.